# I have a URL that opens in IE but not in chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, pdf, internet-explorer

I have some jsp code that looks like this:

`<a href="<c:out value='./file.htm?name=basicName&id=1378' />" />`

the `./file.htm?name=basicName&id=1378` somehow opens as a pdf in IE, but does not open as pdf in chrome. 
Chrome tries to open `file.htm` instead, which doesn't work.

How do I make chrome recognize `./file.htm?name=basicName&id=1378` as a pdf file instead of .htm?

Comment: are you setting the correct mimetype  header in the response while sending it? Below is the list of http mimetypes.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

Comment: @ArpanKanthal I don't know. but wouldn't the mimetype not change from ie to chrome? I need a way for chrome to somehow resolve file.htm?name..... instead of trying to download file.htm right away

Comment: Try setting the response header (Content-type: application/pdf ) and see what happens

Comment: I have set that and also I have added content-disposition attachment. niether has helped, still not working in chrome. Chrome tryies to open the .htm file.

Comment: what happens when you try to access the url directly from the browser instead of through the jsp?